# Parallel operations of image receiving and processing in C

Tags: c, posix, parallel-processing

I am working on UBUNTU platform where I receive images (via `UDP`) from two different cameras (event-based capture) and process the images (3D reconstruction). I want to perform this operation in such a way that while the image receiving operation is in progress, the image processing operation should start in parallel. I know that I can use two posix threads for these two parallel operations. But I am confused how do I synchronize these two threads, so that the `process()` thread should start exactly after at least one pair of images is received by the `receive()` thread. If I make the `process()` thread wait for a `mutex` condition (which will be set by the `receive()` thread every time it will receive a pair of images), the receiving will be much faster than processing and the `receive()` thread may set the condition many times while a single image pair is being processed by the `process()` thread. What could be a better way to achieve this operation?

Comment: If you receiver can outpace the processing, what do you want to do about overall data flow-control?  It's fairly easy to just queue image objects to the processor using a producer-consumer queue, but you have to decide on a data flow-control mechanism first.

Answer (score 2):

Put your images to process (or a pointer to each one, or a struct concerning the info, whatever your mechanism is) on a threadsafe queue in the receive thread. Use a [semaphore](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) or [pthread_cond](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) to signal the processing thread after you've enqueued an item.

The processing thread should block until it received the cond signal and should only block when the queue is empty. When this thread is unblocked, it should pop an image off the queue and begin its work. When it is done processing, it should (at the top of the loop) decide whether to block or to process another image. If the queue is empty, it blocks. If the queue is not empty, it pops an image off and processes it.

Comment: Yes.  The difficulty with video processing/streaming is flow-control.  TheOP needs to decide on a strategy for this as he/she states in the question that the receiver works faster than the processor.

Comment: Ok, so buffer more data before processing. Not sure why this is an issue. He sounded like he had much more fundamental threading issues than what you describe. This is a very common problem and is solved by the same mechanism in addition to multi-buffering, but that buffering is only because you need a temporary sink for the data. We don't need such a sink because we're putting fully-received images on the queue, which is what he wants.